# Android Programming ViewPager from a GridView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am new to android programming and am looking to implement a gallery which has a grid view that then pushes on to a view pager but I am having a few problems getting this to work.  I have it working currently just using a static Image Adapter but am not sure how to change this to use a view pager instead. I also want to be able to add my own titles to each screen but I wasn't sure how to do this or whether it had to be the image name that would appear?

The code I have at the moment is...

the .xml with the grid view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d3d3e" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/phone"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the grid view .java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class Marble extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marble);

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter1(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity1.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

the image adapter .java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.arabescato, R.drawable.biancocarrara,
            R.drawable.botticinoclassico, R.drawable.calacattaoro,
            R.drawable.cremamarfil, R.drawable.cremavalencia,
            R.drawable.emperadordark, R.drawable.jurabeige,
            R.drawable.neromarquina, R.drawable.perlatoolympo,
            R.drawable.rojoalicante

    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter1(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(265, 265));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

and finally the image activity .java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FullImageActivity1 extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter1 imageAdapter1 = new ImageAdapter1(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
}
```

All help on this will be massively appreciated as I'm absolutely stumped!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use swipe for images?

Comment: yes I want it similar to the photo gallery on an iPhone so grid to full screen image with title and then left/right swipe between images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you proceed, add the `android.support.v4` jar file to your project.

You need 2 things: the `ViewPager` in your layout, and an adapter that extends `PagerAdapter`

First change your `full_image.xml` layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create an adapter that extends `PagerAdapter` (required by `ViewPager`)

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

In your `FullImageActivity1` class:

```
public class FullImageActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // Loop through the ids to create a list of full screen image views
        ImageAdapter1 imageAdapter1 = new ImageAdapter1(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter1.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.mThumbIds[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Finally create the adapter
        ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);

        // Set the ViewPager to point to the selected image from the previous activity
        // Selected image id
        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

The general idea is to create an adapter that extends `PagerAdapter` to supply data to the `ViewPager`. For more information, you can visit [Android Docs on PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html)

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thank you so much for this, however could you please help with two errors I am getting with the code. First is in the ImagePageAdapter where it has container.destroyView I have an error that wants me to add cast to 'container? And the second is in the FullImageActivity1 where it has = new ArrayList<ImageView>; it says Syntax error on on token(s), misplaced construct(s)?? Thanks

Comment: Oops, my bad. Typos, please have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: You're an absolute star! works perfectly! all I need to do now is get my search to work to get it to look for titles of the stones in a searchable list view and then to push to the view pager from the results. Also how are your iOS skills?